# The frontend object does not implement the processor_info interface required by the command

Tags: simics

I am trying to run bare metal tests under simics as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/68221424/2095283
but get `The frontend object does not implement the processor_info interface required by the command`

Here is what I do:

- create a new project: `$HOME/simics/simics-6.0.89/bin/project-setup simics-test1 && cd simics-test1`
- create a small config file:

```
% cat t1.simics 
$start = (load-binary ./small)
%rip = $start
%rsp = 0x40001000
%bp.hap.run-until name = X86_HLT_Instr
```

- create a tiny bare metal binary:

```
% cat small.cc 
extern "C" void _start() {
  asm volatile ("mov $42, %rax");
  asm volatile ("hlt");
}
% clang -O2 -static -nostdlib  small.cc -o small 
% objdump -d small

small:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000401000 <_start>:
  401000:       48 c7 c0 2a 00 00 00    mov    $0x2a,%rax
  401007:       f4                      hlt    
  401008:       c3                      retq
```

- Run simics:

```
./simics t1.simics 
Intel Simics 6 (build 6103 linux64) Copyright 2010-2021 Intel Corporation


Use of this software is subject to appropriate license.
Type 'copyright' for details on copyright and 'help' for on-line documentation.

The frontend object does not implement the processor_info interface required by the command
[.../simics-test1/t1.simics:1] error in 'load-binary' command
Error - interrupting script.
```

Comment: Alternatively, is it possible to do the same w/o creating a binary and loading it, i.e. just tell simics what instructions to execute?

Comment: You can always insert bytes into memory and point the instruction pointer at them... but that assumes you have a processor set up. The simplest way to get to a processor + memory is probably to just use the QSP setup but set the disk image to empty and replacing the "bios" variable with your own executable.  The "bios" is loaded into memory on the QSP system setup and will be the first thing executed.

Comment: Would you suggest a place to look for documentation and example for all of this?
"insert bytes into memory" - what is the syntax, and where to find the docs? 
"QSP setup "  is that something in targets/qsp-x86/*? which one? 
"replacing the "bios" variable " - I don't see a "bios" variable in targets/qsp-x86/*. Or is that   default bios_image =
   "%simics%/targets/qsp-x86/images/SIMICSX58IA32X64_1_0_0_bp_r.fd"
?

Comment: I guess I can do run-command-file "./targets/qsp-x86/firststeps-no-network.simics"
and then add mode code. Now I get this: 

Parse error: Empty name space
[/home/kcc/simics-projects/t1/t1.simics:5] error parsing command
Error - interrupting script.

Comment: Sounds like the parse error was addressed in a separate question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68373004/how-to-make-bp-hap-run-until-name-x86-hlt-instr-work

Answer (score 1):

If that is the only setup you do, there is nothing in the Simics configuration that can run  code.  Check the contents of the configuration using `list-objects`. If it just shows a few basic objects, you do not have any machine configured.  Like this:

```
simics> list-objects 
┌─────────────────────────┬───────────────────────┐
│          Class          │         Object        │
├─────────────────────────┼───────────────────────┤
│<bp-manager>             │bp                     │
│<breakpoints-old>        │breakpoints            │
│<frontend-server-console>│frontend_server_console│
│<preferences>            │prefs                  │
│<sim>                    │sim                    │
│<tcf-agent>              │tcf                    │
└─────────────────────────┴───────────────────────┘
```

You can check the presence of processors using `list-processors`. For an empty session, this is what you get:

```
simics> list-processors
No processor found
```

The `load-binary` command operates by default on the current frontend processor. Check which one it is with the `pselect`.   Here is an empty session, again:

```
simics> pselect
No frontend object selected
```

Comment: That explains why my set up is not working.. Maybe you can point me to an example test (.simics file?) based on which I can make my test to work?

Comment: Using the firststeps script is good start. Like you already did.